# SSIS inserting all String values as empty values in postgres Database

Tags: excel, postgresql, ssis, etl

I'm new to SSIS, I'm trying to extract data from an Excel file into Postgres database,
I have tried a small file example that contains only one String column "column1" with 3 lines:

```
ab 
ac
abb
```

And I have created one table with one column in Postgres

I have created a task with excel source, and ODBC destination the connection worked good I can see the data, but when I execute the task I get empty strings in the database.

[image: postgres table screenshot]

I don't know what is the problem can anyone help?

PS: I'm using visual studio 2019, Postgres 9.4 with Pgadmin 3 and I imported Excel as 96-2003

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You will need to post some of your code (at least the part that queries and exports Excel) in order for anyone to provide meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

I used OLEDB connection instead of ODBC connection and it worked